# Seems that no response received on getJSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, jsonp

I am sending the jsonp request as:

```
var jsoncallback = "?jsoncallback=?"
$.getJSON( reportURL + jsoncallback, {
    tags: "",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
          alert( item );
        });
    });
```

I have put an alert to see if the request works. On server side, in node js file I am responding to request as:

```
..
console.log("request received");
response.writeHead( 200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" } );
..
response.end();
```

In the logs I can see that the request received. The problem is that no alert windows pops up.

What could be the reason to this?

Comment: Have you looked in the browser's console log?

Comment: sure. no errors there.

Comment: Your alert is in an each method. Maybe the iteration is not right? Is the data format the right one?

Comment: I moved out the alert from **each** - still nothing

Comment: And when you moved it, did you call alert(item) ? Because tha't gonna fail too. Try out of the each method alert("test")

Comment: alkis, of course I have moved it out from **each**. I even deleted **each** and left only the alert.

Comment: Can you include how you `write()` the `response` in the server? With `jsoncallback=?` in the URL, jQuery is expecting that the response is a JSONP `<script>` with the value of `jsoncallback` written as the "*padding*."

Comment: Jonathat, I write it as i mentioned on the question post - I just reponse.writeHead(...) and (for testing reasons - just the head and end) response.end()

Answer (score 1):

> I just reponse.writeHead(...) and (for testing reasons - just the head and end) response.end()

With the `jsoncallback=?` in the URL, jQuery is expecting a JSONP `<script>` as a response. For this to work, the server should at the very least write out the "*padding*."

That is a call to the function named by `jsoncallback`. And it won't be just `?` -- jQuery replaces that with a pseudo-random function name along the lines of `jQuery1910123456789_0123456789`. For that, the response should at least be:

```
jQuery1910123456789_0123456789();
```

You'll need to get the value from the `request.url`:

```
var parsedUrl = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = parsedUrl.query || {};

if ('jsoncallback' in query) {
    response.write(query.jsoncallback + '();');
}
// ...
```

And, once you have `data` to output with it:

```
if ('jsoncallback' in query) {
    response.write(query.jsoncallback + '(' + JSON.stringify(data) + ');');
} else {
    response.write(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed the JSON is correctly formatted? Check it against http://jsonlint.com/.

From the [getJSON() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the
>   request will usually fail silently.

Comment: if I leave nothing but .writeHead and .end in the server side, I still get no alert popped up.